# Insert into mysql from Bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

Utilized a few posts here and Google and friends and I'm trying desperately to get something simple to work. I want to insert data into mysql via a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
DB_USER='jhatter';
DB_PASSWD='XXXXXXX';

DB_NAME='ppr';
TABLE='graph';

#Collect Rank Information from flightaware.com
day=$(date +"%m/%d/%y")
time=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
rank=$(curl -s http://flightaware.com/adsb/stats/user/jdhatter11 | grep -i site-ranking-29371 | grep window | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/,//)

#mysql commands
mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME
INSERT INTO $TABLE (`id `, `day`, `time`, `rank`) VALUES (NULL, "$day", "$time", "$rank");
QUIT;
```

This script when ran manually stops abrubtly after mysql login. It actually brings the login up on screen and I have been inserted in the database.
I'm a huge novice and please go easy if it's blatant, but why doesn't the script proceed to process the INSERT and instead throw me into mysql. 
I envision this all happening in the background...

Comment: the `insert` query will be a command to the bash script, **NOT** the mysql client. you have to pass the query as an argument to mysql, or via its stdin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass the commands in a *here-document*, like this:

```
mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME << EOF
INSERT INTO $TABLE (\`id\`, \`day\`, \`time\`, \`rank\`) VALUES (NULL, "$day", "$time", "$rank");
EOF
```

Notice that the `` ` `` need to be escaped.
I also removed the `QUIT` command,
as it's unnecessary (good tip @Ven, thanks).

Actually, since those column names don't contain special symbols,
you don't actually need to quote them, and write the INSERT query a bit simpler, like this:

```
mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME << EOF
INSERT INTO $TABLE (id, day, time, rank) VALUES (NULL, "$day", "$time", "$rank");
EOF
```

Comment: Wonderful, in the end I feel like I tried 1 million combinations of similar variations. Thank you for the explanation. SOLVED

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a here-doc if you want to put the input to a program after the program in a script.

```
mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME <<EOF
INSERT INTO $TABLE (\`id\`, \`day\`, \`time\`, \`rank\`) VALUES (NULL, "$day", "$time", "$rank");
EOF
```

Note that you need to escape backticks, because they're part of shell syntax to insert the output of a command into the command line.

For a one-liner, you could also use the `-e` option.

```
mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME -e "NSERT INTO $TABLE (\`id\`, \`day\`, \`time\`, \`rank\`) VALUES (NULL, '$day', '$time', '$rank)"
```