# how to import json file from https web page into a mariadb or mysql database?

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I am trying to import a file into a mariadb (mysql), database. A proof of concept file is in .json format on the web at this location. https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.geojson

I know how to do this on db2 for i.

```
select * from JSON_TABLE(
               SYSTOOLS.HTTPGETCLOB('https://earthquake.usgs.gov' ||
                '/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.geojson',null),
                '$.features[*]'
               COLUMNS( MILLISEC BIGINT PATH '$.properties.time',
                        MAG DOUBLE PATH '$.properties.mag', 
                        PLACE VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.properties.place'
                      )) AS X;
```

This reads a from the web and lists 3 fields. Surrounding it with an insert clause will put it into a database file for me.

I would like to do exactly the same thing on my home server using mariadb. Ultimately a script will run unattended on a hosted server.

A .json segment of the earthquake data looks like this:

```
… "features":[
{"type":"Feature",
    "properties":{
        "mag":1.1,
        "place":"58 km WNW of Anchor Point, Alaska",
        "time":1640472257402,
        "updated":1640472615410,
        "tz":null,
        "url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak021gi3al5x",
        "detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/ak021gi3al5x.geojson",
        "felt":null,
        "cdi":null,
        "mmi":null,
        "alert":null,
        "status":"automatic",
        "tsunami":0,
        "sig":19,
        "net":"ak",
        "code":"021gi3al5x",
        "ids":",ak021gi3al5x,",
        "sources":",ak,",
        "types":",origin,",
        "nst":null,
        "dmin":null,
        "rms":0.79,
        "gap":null,
        "magType":"ml",
        "type":"earthquake",
        "title":"M 1.1 - 58 km WNW of Anchor Point, Alaska"},
        "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[-152.8406,59.9119,89.7]
        },
        "id":"ak021gi3al5x"
    }, ...
```

Comment: Show your effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors you need help with and example output that you expect. That said there are a lot of beginner tutorials online, have you done any research before asking here?

Comment: Kind of interesting question.  Are you just looking to store the time, mag and place or the whole dataset ?  What were you planning to use to get the data and store it ?  A front-end running on a server, a bash script, etc.  Seems like you could even write a script that would get the data via CURL.

Comment: Thanks you, @Ron. Believe me, I've looked up and down the mariadb and mysql tutorials and guides, and found nothing there addressing the topic of importing then parsing external .json data. That's why I resorted to asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, but you could maybe just write a BASH script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh


cd "$(dirname "$0")"
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
TODAY=`date +"%d%b%Y-%H%M"`

MYSQL_HOST='127.0.0.1'
MYSQL_PORT='3306'
MYSQL_USER='root'
MYSQL_PASSWORD='root'


url=https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.geojson
DATA=$(curl ${url} 2>/dev/null)
printf '%s' "$DATA" | awk '{print $0}'
exit

...
...
...
```

and then use a tool like https://webinstall.dev/jq/, Python and whatever other tools you have on your system to extract the data that you want and then update the DB.

I am more familiar with PHP, which would work also.  You could tidy that up a bit, but seems to work actually.

[image]

[image]

**earthquake.php**

```
<?php
$database = false;
try {

    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true );
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test;port=3306;charset=utf8','root','root', $options);


} catch (PDOException $e) {

    // Echo custom message. Echo error code gives you some info.
    echo '[{"error":"Database connection can not be estabilished. Please try again later.  Error code: ' . $e->getCode() . '"}]';
    exit;
}

$url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.geojson";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$features = json_decode($result)->features;
foreach ($features as $feature) {
    echo 'Mag:  '.$feature->properties->mag.', Place:  '.$feature->properties->place.', '.gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $feature->properties->time/1000).PHP_EOL;
    $query = 'INSERT INTO features (mag, place, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    $params = [$feature->properties->mag, $feature->properties->place, gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $feature->properties->time/1000)];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query) or die ('["status":{"error":"Prepare Statement Failure","query":"' .$query . '"}]');
    $stmt->execute($params) or die('[{"error":"' . $stmt->errorInfo()[2]  . '","query":"' .$query . '","params":' .json_encode($params) . '}]');

}

?>
```

create a local DB called features with mag, place and time columns.  If you have php on your system just run it from the CLI, php earthquake.php

e.g. [Insert into mysql from Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215064/insert-into-mysql-from-bash-script)

I use Laravel a bit, and would probably actually build my own model and use Eloquent and a little UI to handle that, but using a script seems like an option.

Comment: You have to mess around with the decimal insert so it doesn't round.  Using 3,2 for the Decimal might work.

Comment: Thank you @SScotti. You even wrote the code for me! I'd digesting what you gave me now.

Comment: If you have php on your system, it should work.  Not too familiar with jq, but that seems like it would be an option also.  Probably a pretty common application to ingest data from a JSON request.  Just save the file and then from the terminal:  php path/to/earthquake.php